# Kotlin generics inheritance

Tags: scala, kotlin

I have a base class Base, and two traits let's say Trait1 and Trait2.

I want to write a parametrized class with all these three things.

In scala I do:

```
class C[T <: Base with Trait1 with Trait2] { … }
```

In kotlin I'm trying:

```
class C<T : Base, Trait1, Trait2> { … }
```

but it's no good, Trait1 and Trait2 are more type parameters.

Is there a way to write this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Noah's answer and [this page](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#upper-bounds) suggest, you should use `where` to specify multiple upper bounds:

```
class C<T: Base> where T: Trait1, T: Trait2 {...}
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know that would compile!

Comment: Nice! And I did dig into the grammar but typeConstraints was too far from typeParameters ^^; Thank you!